# limit the max value for an input in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm pretty new in coding with RoR and I'm using Haml, and since I'm doing a school project I decided to give it a try. The thing is that I encountered an issue. There's an attribute in my object `producto`, `req_quantity` which is the quantity of a certain product a client requested. In my views, I have an input box for the admin to authorize the quantity the client requested

```
.col-xs-2
  .text-center
     = product.input :auth_quantity, label: false, required: "required"
```

I'd like to limit `:auth_quantity` to be less or equal to `req_quantity` since currently is allowing values greater than `req_quantity`.

This is my first question since I googled and I don't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Is this a numerical field only?

Comment: Yep, is a numerical field only. In my database I have it as a double precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I basically solved it like this. Thanks for the answer, made me think a lot!!

`.col-xs-2
  .text-center
     = producto.input :auth_quantity, input_html: { min: '0', max: product.object.req_quantity, step: 'any' }, label: false, required: "required"`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it in haml:

```
.col-xs-2
  .text-center
     = product.input :auth_quantity, type: "number", max: "<%= producto.req_quantity  %>" label: false, required: "required"
```

Where `producto.req_quantity` is the numerical value of the quantity of a certain product a client requested.

Comment: I tried but it isn't working. I also tried with `max: "3"` and still allows me to input numbers greater than 3.

Comment: have you tried adding a minimum value too ? `min: "1"`